# How to fix error "Could not locate device support files"

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the latest Xcode 11.1
iOS is updated to the latest release 13.2

I'm getting error:

```
 Could not locate device support files.

 This iPhone 6s is running iOS 13.2 (17B84), which may 
 not be supported by this version of Xcode. An updated 
 version of Xcode may be found on the           
 App Store or at developer.apple.com.
```

This happens to all iOS devices running 13.2

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been reading about hacks to get it to work on the current version of Xcode. Honestly not interested in going down that path. Bottom line, Apple released iOS/iPadOS 13.2 but did not release Xcode 11.2 (still in beta). Gotta go to developer.apple.com and download the latest beta of Xcode 11.2 to run apps on both iOS and iPadOS 13.2 devices. Hopefully they release Xcode 11.2 soon. The last beta was from Oct 11.

Comment: You can copy the 13.2 support files over from Xcode 11.2 beta and they will work in Xcode 11.1.  Just in case you're tied to a specific version.

Answer (score 5):

That's easy.
Those files are contained in Xcode itself.
Thus, all you have to do to use devices with a newer iOS version - create junction folder (hard link) of those support files from new Xcode (in our case - the beta 11.2) to older Xcode (11.1).

And yes, before that you have to download beta Xcode 11.2.

Otherwise, you also can download only support files from the Internet, if someone already shared them and just toss 'em to Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

P.S. to create junction folder use this command in terminal:

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.2 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

It allows you to not to duplicate the same files across your Mac

P.S. **Be aware!** You have to launch newer Xcode (Beta) you downloaded at least one time to install updated Xcode Tools before you can use symlinks (hard links, junction folder) to Device Support files in older Xcode, otherwise you'll get an error and will not be able to build your app.

Comment: Is there any link for device support files for iOS 13.2+

Comment: The ones for 13.3 don't seem to be available yet, https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport