# IOS 13.2 (17B84) Device Support files for Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios13, xcode11.1

"This iPhone is running iOS 13.2 (17B84), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode. An updated version of Xcode may be found on the App Store or at developer.apple.com."

Does anybody have the IOS 13.2(17B84) Device Support files for Xcode 11.1 ?

Thank you..

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. Just install Xcode 11.2.1.

Comment: @rmaddy may be some body does not want/able to, what's problem with it?

Comment: I see this as a warning in Devices and Simulators menu for Xcode 10.3: This iPhone 8 (Model A1863, A1905, A1906, A1907) is running iOS 13.4.1 (17E262), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode. I can't upgrade to 11.2.1 because my team uses an older version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I downloaded the support files I needed from here:

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

and added them to:

Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

and the error was fixed. It just needed to debug the phone (automatically) and it worked fine. I'm still even using Xcode 10.1, but with all the support files it builds on my iPhone fine that is updated to IOS 13.2

Comment: Quite helpfull link!

Comment: Helpfull link,
Thanks

Comment: I got my Xcode 11 crashed by adding iOS 13.5 supporting files

Comment: Thank you!!  This helped me with the same issue, but tvOS.  For the commenter on the OP question - I'm in the same boat as the asker because my MacBook pro is from 2009, which limits which version of OS and subsequently Xcode I can use.

Answer (score 2):

**For 15.3**

I've got success by using the 15.2 support files after renaming to 15.3.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can find the device files in the beta version of Xcode, according to this answer:
[How to fix error "Could not locate device support files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647195/how-to-fix-error-could-not-locate-device-support-files)